# Identify process sending invalid emails

Tags: sql-server, email, ssis

I am having a issue in my company. We are getting a bunch of bad email delivery failure notifications either from a SQL Job, stored procedure, SSIS package or something else. Below is the sample Delivery failure email.

> Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:
>
> NoLonger.Exists@somewhere.com
>
> Your message wasn't delivered because the recipient's email provider rejected it.
>
> Diagnostic information for administrators:
>
> Generating server: server-3.bemta-4.messagelabs.com
>
> NoLonger.Exists@somewhere.com
>
> Remote Server returned '< #5.7.0 smtp; 551 5.7.0 recipient domain does not exist in DNS>'
>
> Original message headers:
>
> Return-Path: 
>   Received: from [85.158.143.35] by server-3.bemta-4.messagelabs.com id C4/27-29399-60505E45; Wed, 18 Feb 2015 21:32:54 +0000
>   Received: (qmail 4065 invoked from network); 18 Feb 2015 21:32:54 -0000
>       Received: from a96-076-static.datachambers.com (HELO ussmtp02.hvwan.net) (204.15.96.76)
>         by server-14.tower-21.messagelabs.com with SMTP; 18 Feb 2015 21:32:54 -0000
>       Received: from MCR-SWEB01.hcop.us.hvwan.net ([10.73.65.2])
>                 by ussmtp02.hvwan.net (IBM Domino Release 9.0.1FP1)
>                 with ESMTP id 2015021821325373-22365 ;
>                 Wed, 18 Feb 2015 21:32:53 +0000 
>       X-Env-Sender: sqladmin@elsewhere.com
>       X-Msg-Ref: server-14.tower-21.messagelabs.com!1424295174!12730599!1
>       X-Originating-IP: [204.15.96.76]
>       X-StarScan-Received:
>       X-StarScan-Version: 6.13.4; banners=elsewhere.com,-,-
>       X-VirusChecked: Checked
>       Subject: =?iso-8859-1?Q?PART_REJECT_NMN#:_26477,_PN:_585864804?=
>       Sender: "=?iso-8859-1?Q?sqladmin@yad=2Ecom?=" 
>       From: "=?iso-8859-1?Q?sqladmin@yad=2Ecom?=" 
>       Date: Wed, 18 Feb 2015 16:32:12 -0500
>       To: "=?iso-8859-1?Q?carlton=2Eevans@yad=2Ecom?="
>               ,
>               "=?iso-8859-1?Q?norman=2Ebuckhouse@anonymizing=2Ecom?="
>               ,
>               "=?iso-8859-1?Q?scott=2Echaney@yad=2Ecom?="
>               ,
>               "=?iso-8859-1?Q?jay=2Evandevoorde@yad=2Ecom?="
>               ,
>               "=?iso-8859-1?Q?elliott=2Eortiz@yad=2Ecom?="
>               ,
>               "=?iso-8859-1?Q?robert=2Ewallace@anonymizing=2Ecom?="
>               
>       CC: "=?iso-8859-1?Q?carlton=2Eevans@anonymizingAgain=2Ecom?="
>               ,
>               "=?iso-8859-1?Q?wesley=2Ewasden@yad=2Ecom?="
>               
>       X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
>       X-MSMail-Priority: Normal
>       MIME-Version: 1.0
>       X-Mailer: JMail 4.4 by Dimac
>       X-MIMETrack: Itemize by SMTP Server on ussmtp02.hvwan.net/Servers/yad(Release
>        9.0.1FP1|April  03, 2014) at 02/18/2015 09:32:53 PM,
>               Serialize by Router on ussmtp02.hvwan.net/Servers/yad(Release
>        9.0.1FP1|April  03, 2014) at 02/18/2015 09:32:54 PM,
>               Serialize complete at 02/18/2015 09:32:54 PM,
>               Itemize by SMTP Server on ussmtp01.hvwan.net/Servers/yad(Release
>        9.0.1FP1|April  03, 2014) at 02/18/2015 09:32:57 PM,
>               Serialize by Router on ussmtp01.hvwan.net/Servers/yad(Release
>        9.0.1FP1|April  03, 2014) at 02/18/2015 09:33:00 PM
>       X-TNEFEvaluated: 1
>       Message-ID: 
>       Content-Type: text/html; charset="US-ASCII"
>       Content-Disposition: inline

If you see the top of the Delivery Failure notification instead of `NoLonger.Exists@anonymizing.com`, inside a stored procedure or a DTS script or a job, we have `carlton.evan@somewhere.com`.

How can I solve this problem without going through each and every stored procedure or the SSIS packages on the server?

Comment: I don't know of any way other than updating the hardcoded values to the new hardcoded values how you can solve this. I would suggest storing these email addresses in a table and stop hardcoding them.

Comment: Hi Sean , Yes that would be an ideal scenario to do things when you deal with any emails , putting them in a table . I just joined the company and they have given me this task ... i will do my best to see each and every store procs etc on the sql server

Comment: 1) Have your Exchange admin recreate the account as a distribution group to notify those that need to know. 2) Replace every reference to that account to something more graceful, like a proper distribution list. Then it becomes someone else's problem to manage, not yours

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have entered a bad domain for the recipient.  Husqvarnaroup instead of husqvarnagroup

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id), *
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE definition LIKE '%yourharcodeemail@dontdoit.again%'
```

to check if its on your procedures but if you have it hardcoded you should change it to a table so it wouldn't happen again